# Best practice to get 1:n database relations into code

Tags: sql, oop, design-patterns, relational-database

Imagine a database with two tables like this:

```
persons
---------
|pid|name|
|  0| Tom|
|  1|Hans|
|  2| Ken|
---------

cars
---------------
|cid|pid|  car|
|  0|  1|  BMW|
|  1|  1| Audi|
|  2|  2| Benz|
---------------
```

A 1:n relation between persons and cars.

What is the best practice to associate these in code?

Let's assume I'd like to fill this simple class:

```
class Person {
  string name;
  List<string> cars;
}
```

From the top of my head I could go three ways:

Way 1:

Do two queries separately and do a nested foreach
to associate all cars.

Two SQL Queries:

```
SELECT * FROM persons;
SELECT * FROM cars;
```

With the simplistic pseudo code:

```
List<Person> personList;
foreach(row in personQuery) {
  person = new Person(personQuery.name);
  foreach(row in carQuery)
    if(carQuery.pid == personQuery.pid)
      person.AddCar(carQuery.car);
}
```

Way 2:

Do one query with a join and ignore duplicate information.

One SQL Query:

```
 SELECT * FROM persons JOIN cars ON persons.pid = cars.pid;
```

With:

```
List<Person> personList;
int lastID;
foreach(row in Query) {
  if(Query.pid != lastID) {
    person = new Person(personQuery.name);
    personList.Add(person);
  }
  person.AddCar(Query.car);
}
```

Way 3:

Do one query to get all persons and then one for each person to
get the associated cars.

Many SQL Queries:

```
SELECT * FROM persons;
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE pid = @param;
```

With:

```
List<Person> personList;
foreach(row in personQuery) {
  person = new Person(personQuery.name);
  carQuery = DoCarQuery(personQuery.pid);
  foreach(row in carQuery)
    person.AddCar(carQuery.car);
  personList.Add(person);
}
```

In my testing it seems like the first way is the fastest, but it degrades really fast because it's a n^m approach and it gets even slower if I have multiple
1:n relations like a third table with "bikes" in the example above.

I encounter this problem regularly in my work and couldn't find a best practice only, though this could be because I couldn't word the problem accurately, because I only found matches on how to make 1:n databases in the first place :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I can speak to a generic best practice but some thoughts assuming that you need to load all persons and all cars associated with them:

Most likely you don't want to load all of them if you are displaying them. There would most likely a paging scheme of some sort so that when the data grows to be unmanagable.

The first approach could be improved if you looped through the people first, adding the to some sort of hashtable or dictionary, then looped through cars (ordered by person id) and added them to the cars collection for the specified person like this

```
Dictionary<Guid, Person> personList = new Dictionary<Guid, Person>();
foreach(row in personQuery)  {
  person = new Person(personQuery.name);
  personList.Add(person.pid, person);

}

Person currentPerson = null
foreach(row in carQuery.OrderBy(c=>c.pid) {
    if(currentPerson == null || carQuery.pid != currentPerson.pid)
    {
       currentPerson = personList[carQuery.pid];
    }
    currentPerson.AddCar(carQuery.car);
}
```

The way it is written has it looping through all cars for each person so (n * m where n is the total number of cars and m is the total number of people).

The second approach would be the most efficient in that it would loop n times where n is the total number of cars. However, you are right that if you extend this loop to a third relationship, it grows exponentially

The third approach is the worst in that you would be calling the database n + 1 times (n is still the total number of cars) and querying a database is much less efficient then looping.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The idea to create a hash on the first loop is really interesting and would definitely improve cycle times, like you said from n^m to n*m. Good thinking!

Answer (score 1):

First, your best practice (if you haven't already) is to create a FOREIGN KEY on Cars.pid that REFERENCES Persons.pid. This will ensure database integrity. You can also cascade changes (deletes are common) so that if a person is removed, their associated car records are also removed.

To answer your specific questions about your 3 scenarios. The answer really depends on what you are doing with the data.

- Number 1 is simply 2 separate SQL queries that don't associate the data at all. You won't find many use cases for this except to display 2 separate lists of data, or if you need those 2 data sets separate in an application. Using a nested loop to combine the data defeats the purpose of using a *Relational* DBMS. It probably seems like this is the fastest way for now, but you are putting the load on your application instead of the database management system that was designed to handle the process. As you are finding, this will get *exponentially* slower as you add n^ tables to the mix.
- Number 2 is really the only example that you have that actually relates the data through a query. You will find that this is the best practice in the vast majority of cases and you will use this simple JOIN often. You should not be getting duplicate information if you are querying for a specific pid, you will get all of the cars associated with that pid.
- Number 3 is effectively the same thing as number one except using a variable as an input for one of the queries.

The best practice here to retrieve all of the cars associated with a person is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM persons JOIN cars ON persons.pid = cars.pid 
WHERE persons.name = @param
```

Since you only have the input of the name, this may return a few duplicates if name is not unique, but it will perform much better than querying the entire persons AND cars table and then filtering out a single value in your application.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. In the database foreign key relations are of course set, this was just a simple example.

The query you posted is of course used if I only need all cars for one person, which would fall under Lazy Loading I guess.
I was just loading all for the sake of simplicity
My main problem is really that even with Lazy Loading I get so many sets returned that the performance degrades fast. Even if I avoid string operations and such.

Comment: The real question is, do you need to display all of the data sets? Or just a small subset or a single record?

Comment: The above was just an example, in my actual project the data sets are already heavily filtered and/or paged and it's still a lot of sets :/